# asp.net controls that may appear outside of form tag with runat="server"

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I am experimenting with asp.net controls and came across [this article](https://www.quanzhanketang.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.html) that states that `All server controls must appear within a <form> tag, and the <form> tag must contain the runat="server" attribute.`.

I tried to run a simple aspx page with no form and a table `asp:table` and it renders fine. I also tried the same with a label and it's fine too. With a button on the other hand, it returns an error page that claims that a button control must appear within a form tag with a `runat="server"` attribute, as expected.

What distincts controls that may appear outside a form tag from those which must appear within a form tag? I could not find anything on docs.microsoft

Comment: My thought is that buttons are expected to have events associated with them in the code-behind page, so they will throw an error if that code isn't found.  The code-behind page can't "see" a control that isn't marked with the ```runat="server"``` attribute, so perhaps this combination is why some controls throw an error if not contained in a form with the ```runat="server"``` attribute.

Comment: is this a web form that was made with a master page? In that case, you don't require a form tag. (there is already one from the master page!) So, as a general rule, you may not have to place controls inside of the form tag, but you should - since that will be the assumption for all code behind and all markup. Some of it might work, but why spend a few extra hours trying to make somthing work when it does not? Failure to follow this layout RIGHT after adding a new page will just wind up costing you hours of time and things not working.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the initial tests "render fine" but would have other bugs under various edge cases.  For example, if any of those controls need to persist any state across page loads, they would likely fail to do so.

Basically, *nothing* distinguishes controls which work vs. don't work outside of the over-arching form.  None of them are guaranteed to work outside of the form.  Always put WebForms controls within the over-arching `<form>` that encloses each page.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not looking for best practices, I want a clear way to distinguish between controls that will crash the page and ones that won't

Comment: @GalSuchetzky: For what purpose?  *None* of the controls are guaranteed to work outside of the framework's intended use.  They won't all "crash the page" when it renders, but they will all fail in some way under some circumstances.  What is the goal of wanting to introduce such bugs into the system rather than just using the framework as intended?

Comment: I am not currently developing any system, I just want to understand the details better about what work and what doesn't.

Comment: @GalSuchetzky: If the question is "which ASP.NET controls will **safely** work or are in any way **guaranteed** to work outside of a `<form>`" then the answer is "none".  They all rely on posted form data at some point, even if it's just for viewstate.

Comment: And things like page.DataBind()? Again, the controls should be in a form. So for best practices? Don't bother to screw around - just put your controls inside of the form tags, and you be fine (so that's the best practice - anything else is just you screwing around and wasting your time).